# What is the difference between TRUNC and TO_DATE in Hive

Tags: sql, oracle, hadoop

Hi i trying to find out what the difference between using a TRUNC and TO_DATE is in Hive.

Currently within oracle I wrote the following case statement against the Data shown below:

```
ORDER_NO | NAME | DATE_ | TASK_NO
ABC123 | Humpty | 07-OCT-16 12:30:54 | 1
ABC123 | Humpty | 07-OCT-16 12:30:54 | 2
ABC123 | Humpty | 07-OCT-16 12:32:20 | 6

SELECT ORDER_NO, NAME, DATE_, TASK_NO
    (CASE WHEN DATE_ - LAG(DATE_) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_NO, NAME, TRUNC(DATE_) ORDER BY DATE_) <= 1/48  
    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS COUNT1
```

and this gives me the result:

```
ORDER_NO | NAME | DATE_ | TASK_NO | COUNT1
    ABC123 | Humpty | 07-OCT-16 12:30:54 | 1 | 1
    ABC123 | Humpty | 07-OCT-16 12:30:54 | 2 | 0
    ABC123 | Humpty | 07-OCT-16 12:32:20 | 6 | 1
```

which is correct. Now if i use the same query in Hive against my full data set I get an error message:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns.
```

So I changed the TRUNC to TO_DATE and this works and gives me the following results:

```
SELECT ORDER_NO, NAME, DATE_, TASK_NO
(CASE WHEN DATE_ - LAG(DATE_) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_NO, NAME, TO_DATE(DATE_) ORDER BY DATE_) <= 1/48  
    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS COUNT1
```

and this gives me the result:

```
ORDER_NO | NAME | DATE_ | TASK_NO | COUNT1
ABC123 | Humpty | 07-OCT-16 12:30:54 | 1 | 1
ABC123 | Humpty | 07-OCT-16 12:32:20 | 6 | 1        
ABC123 | Humpty | 07-OCT-16 12:30:54 | 2 | 1
```

which is different to what I get in Oracle. From what I can gather the date value is stored as a string as the results arent ordered in Date/Time and this is where I think the problem lies but not sure what changes I need to make to fix it.

Would really appreciate some advice.

---

UPDATED CODE:

```
SELECT  
ORDER_NO
,NAME
,DATE_FIXED
,TASK_NO
,CASE WHEN DATE_UTS - LAG(DATE_UTS) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_NO, NAME, TO_DATE(DATE_FIXED) ORDER BY DATE_FIXED) <= 60*30
THEN    0
ELSE    1
END AS COUNT1
FROM
(
SELECT
ORDER_NO
,NAME
,TASK_NO
,FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_, 'DD-MMM-YY HH:MM:SS')) AS DATE_FIXED
,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_, 'DD-MMM-YY HH:MM:SS') AS DATE_UTS
FROM TABLE1
) T
```

Comment: What is type of column `DATE_`?

Comment: Thanks Kacper, the DATE_ in oracle is down as a Date Datatype.

Comment: What is the DATE_ type is Hive?

Comment: The DATE_ type in Hive is down as a string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## 1

[Hive Operators and User-Defined Functions (UDFs)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

> to_date
>
> Returns the date part of a timestamp string (pre-Hive 2.1.0):
> to_date("1970-01-01 00:00:00") = "1970-01-01".
> As of Hive 2.1.0, returns a date object.
> Prior to Hive 2.1.0 ([HIVE-13248](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13248)) the return type was a String because no Date type existed when the method was created.

---

> trunc
>
> Returns date truncated to the unit specified by the format (as of Hive
> 1.2.0).
> Supported formats: MONTH/MON/MM, YEAR/YYYY/YY.
> Example: trunc('2015-03-17', 'MM') = 2015-03-01.

## 2

You have errors in your original query

1. There was no comma between `TASK_NO` and `(CASE WHEN`
2. `Trunc` in Hive must take 1 parameter, and there is no parameter for day.
3. There is no minus operator for dates (and definitly not for strings). This results in a NULL.

## 3

The only recognize date format in Hive is **YYYY-MM-DD** which does not match your data.
Applying date functions on invalid string result in NULL.

This is how you convert your data format to dates:

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('07-OCT-16 12:30:54','dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss'));
OK
2016-10-07 12:30:54
```

---

and the whole query:

```
select  ORDER_NO
       ,NAME
       ,DATE_fixed
       ,TASK_NO
       
       ,case 
            when    DATE_uts 
                -   LAG(DATE_uts) OVER 
                    (
                        PARTITION BY    ORDER_NO,NAME,to_date(DATE_fixed) 
                        ORDER BY        DATE_fixed
                    )
                <= 60*30
            then    0
            else    1
        end             AS COUNT1
    
from   (select  ORDER_NO
               ,NAME
               ,TASK_NO
               ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(DATE_,'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss'))   as DATE_fixed
               ,unix_timestamp(DATE_,'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss')                  as DATE_uts
               
        from    t
        ) t
;
```

---

```
ABC123  Humpty  2016-10-07 12:30:54 2   1
ABC123  Humpty  2016-10-07 12:30:54 1   0
ABC123  Humpty  2016-10-07 12:32:20 6   0
```

---

**This were also the results when I tested it on Oracle**

Comment: Please take a look

Comment: Thanks Dudu will do, what is the workaround to have this as a date?

Comment: I'm just checking something for you

Comment: Thanks Dudu for pointing out the issues. Apologies the comma was missed out when I was typing the question but is there in the query. In regards to your query just going to try that now, had a question tho, would the order by not need a trunc as otherwise this wont order it right?

Comment: I have ran the code and this gives me the results in date order now but the count1 results are still not right as all showing as 1.. Thanks btw for your help, really appreciate your time. Just seen your comment about the recognized date format...

Comment: There are more errors then working code :-) still editing

Comment: Thanks really appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131268/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-user3191160).

Comment: Done, Please read 2. and 3. again. P.s. I've tested your code and data on Oracle and got different results than those you put in your post

Comment: Thanks for putting the code together. Wow! will give that a go and let you know how i get on.

Comment: Hi Dudu, I have written the code and just ran the first select code but the date_fixed and date_uts both show values as NULL
Tried it with the whole code as well and still shows progress date as NULL and the count1 have all 1s in there.

Comment: Probably a mismatch between the actual dates` format to what you have put in the post